# How to enable showPermaLogin in typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

Why showPermaLogin property (felogin) is not working on TYPO3 9.5.4 ?

I have tried to add these code

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile = fileadmin/pricingdesign/resources/private/layouts/logintest.html
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showPermaLogin = 2
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showForgotPasswordLink = 2
```

All code in Typoscript file

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderby = sorting
  }
   includeCSS {
    screen = fileadmin/pricingdesign/resources/private/assets/css/signin.css
    screen.title = display
    screen.media = screen
    bootstrap = fileadmin/pricingdesign/resources/private/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
  }
  bodyTag = <body class="text-center">
}

plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile = fileadmin/pricingdesign/resources/private/layouts/logintest.html
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showPermaLogin = 2
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showForgotPasswordLink = 2
```

This has just only showed  'Forgot your password?' on result page and no something like 'Remember login'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f9oz.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your template contains the correct parts, there are 2 common reasons why the checkbox might not be shown:

1. `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['permalogin']` is not `0` (allowed, off by default) or `1` (allowed, on by default). -1 will disable it completely, 2 will force it enabled.
2. `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['lifetime']` is set to 0 (or less). This will set the cookie lifetime to 0, which will delete the cookie when the session ends, so perma login will do nothing and it will not be shown.

Also you don't have to set `plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showPermaLogin` to `2`. This variable is boolean, so should be `0` or `1` (in your case `1`). This should not affect the result though as `2` is also seen as `true`.

Comment: After following all steps in your comment it works fluently. Thank you for your supporting :)